# Failure to run or emulate basic apps in Android Studio 2.3.1

Tags: java, android, android-studio

After the Android Studio 2.3.1 update, no apps , not even Hello World run. When clicked on run this error is shown.

> Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
>   Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pre-dex 'C:\Android.android\build-cache\d6387c5ba7dcecea41b28c91351efa5624be8874\output\jars\classes.jar' to 'C:\Users\Deven\AndroidStudioProjects\ErrCheck\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dex\debug\folders\1000\10\classes_bff1bfdc5860437f946a228fbddc9242cb4ec753'

This is just for a hello world application without any edit.

Here's my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

  compileSdkVersion 25
  buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
  defaultConfig {
      applicationId "com.example.android.errcheck"
      minSdkVersion 23
      targetSdkVersion 25
      versionCode 1
      versionName "1.0"
      testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
      multiDexEnabled true
  }

  buildTypes {
      release {
          minifyEnabled false
          proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
      }
   }
}

dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
   })
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
   compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
   testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: `Build > Clean Project` Wait for Cleaning Ends and then `Build > Rebuild Project`

Comment: I tried but same error. Even build apk doesn't work.

Comment: have you enabled MultiDex??

Comment: try to clear cache and restart Android Studio, if still problem persist then show your build.gradle

Comment: Tried enabling multiDex but same error.

Comment: @AbhishekAryan build.gradle is up but main thing to notice is I've made no changes whatsoever because I was trying to test if problem still persists in a basic app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a fault of Android Studio itself. I needed to reinstall it and the bug has been fixed in later versions.